# Symfony4 - Casting env variable issue

Tags: symfony

apparently, Symfony cast env variable is not working on symfony 4.0.

I have this configuration:

```
cache:
    session:
        enabled: "%env(bool:SESSION_CACHE_ENABLED)%"
```

But I get this error:

```
Invalid type for path "cache.session.enabled". Expected boolean, but got string.
```

What is my problem? I'm using symfony version 4.0

Thanks

**EDIT**

Probably, it is a problem of the plugins. That's what I think: Symfony 4 is now based on .env config variable, that are STRING as default; to  handle this, S4 is able to use "casting" env var

'%env(bool:myvar)%'

And it works; if you do a var_dump within a controller, you can see that the variable is a boolean.

Most of current plugins, also those who supports S4, are not able to use this syntax, so, they see that variable as STRING, and the validator return an error.

These plugins should be fixed or, actually, I can duplicate the .yml file on each package/{env}/ dir with separated configuration ( the situation that I would avoid with .env )

Comment: Did you try to remove `bool:`?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is fixed in symfony 4.1 https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/22151